# Media Queries for Header Background Image

Tags: css, media-queries

Trying to set the appropriate (meaning media query for the background header image in which will display the header image as it should be) of the website careertechpa.org. As you might see in the image attached, on the larger desktop screens, the bottom is getting cut off.

[oversized-background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5wB0.jpg)

Here's the code for the header image:

```
.header-one{ height:200px; 
background-image: url('careertechpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/…); 
background-size:102%; }
```

I tried setting this media query but it didn't seem to work.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
    /* styles for MacBook Pro-sized screens and larger */
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: have you set the height of the header?..post your full code here..so that everyone can help you

Comment: I advise against putting any text in the background, you'll be trying to work around problems at different widths/heights when going repsonsive.Your code will only affect that header from infinitely wide down to 1440px so you might not even be seeing its effects depending on your viewport size.

Comment: Yes I set the height of the header. Here's the code for it: .header-one{
 height:200px;
 background-image: url('https://www.careertechpa.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/cropped-Careertechpa-Home-Page-1-header-5.png');
 background-size:102%;
}.   @NathanielFlick this is pre-approved design work with text being in the background image of the header so I can't really change it from a design perspective unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @jgar17 please post your code to your question. And you need to define what you mean by "appropriate" for the media query?

Comment: @NathanielFlick edited my question. Now do you understand what I mean?

Comment: @jgar17 Unfortunately a media query won't fix this. You first need to use background-size: cover but this resizes the bg image to always fit its container, but this means the text might not always be visible where you want it.

Comment: @NathanielFlick so the background-size: cover should be set to 1440 px, and maybe I should get rid of the text in the image but enter that in separate using the same font and size but have it float in the header where I need it to?

Comment: @jgar17 just background-size: cover (no px declaration) and yes separate text to control it

Comment: @NathanielFlick thank you for the input. The background-size: cover worked for smaller screen but still is not working for bigger screens.

Comment: Hard to fix this without all your code.

Comment: @NathanielFlick What more do you need and where do you need it from? I gave you the heading code and that seemed to be good enough before?

Comment: @jgar17 you mention a problem that I cannot see?